# How to delete Document folder from Start Menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, documents

How can I delete this folder using the registry?
Is there a way?

Comment: Try this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-remove-the-my-documents-folder/4c9516ab-43aa-41c5-84ed-10a885a485a5

Comment: Where do you see it?

Comment: See this>>>>https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-add-or-remove-folders-in-start-menu-of-windows-10/